# Double crank to single?

Tags: crankset

I just wanna know if I can take off one of the chainrings for this crankset before I buy it off craigslist. Thanks!!

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLxcz.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is to run a single chainring setup, then yes, it is possible.

However you may need some spacers, five in this case, to make up for the thickness of the removed gear. This spacers may be simple washers, but they have to closely match the hole diameter of the chainring and, of course, the thickness.
You can also cut them from sacrificial chainrings.

There is also the option to find single chainring specific bolts, but some vendors may offer them at a higher price than the crankset you want to buy.

Comment: `sacrificial chainrings` sound like something `steampunk Aztecs` would have used to do.